# Angular ng-bind-html unwrapping anchor tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am using ng-bind-html on the below code:

```
<a href="/test">
    <article>
        <p>
            Some content goes here
        </p>
    </article>
</a>
```

I am doing this so the whole content area is one big anchor.
However, when using ng-bind-html I get the following output:

```
<!-- my anchor tag is closed and stripped! -->
<a></a>
<p>
     Some content goes here
</p>
```

When explicitly escaping the output using $sce.trustAsHtml:

```
<!-- anchor tag closed -->
<a href="/test"></a>
<article>
    <!-- random anchor added to the top of every nested element -->
    <a href="/test"></a>

    <p>
        Some content goes here
    </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by making a custom directive that acts like an anchor. When this is added to a surrounding div it does not attract the issue above.

```
exports.directive('anchor', [function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                element.addClass('anchor');
                element.on('click', function () {
                    window.location.href = attributes.anchor;
                });
            }
        };

    }]);
```